# Is there any WIFI RTT for flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I was working on a project where I need the WIFI RTT(Round Trip Time). For those who want to know what's WIFI RTT here is the details https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-rtt

Now my problem is that even after searching for huge amount of time, I did not find it. It will be really helpful if someone answers my query.
Thank you

Comment: Write your own [platform channel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) to access the RTT data? A quick search brings up [this open issue for a popular Flutter plugin](https://github.com/alternadom/WiFiFlutter/issues/140)